# Exclude pom.xml in maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

i am currently writing an Java Project, which contains of very little projects.
And to remove repeating copy paste for each new project, I made a maven archetype.

The problem:
The main project is a maven parent project and each new one should be assigned to it.
But everytime I call "new module -> archetype and then use my archetype" it uses its own pom.xml.
But I don't want that, because the pom maven automatically generates fits my doings.

Is there a way to keep the generated one and exclude the pom from the archetype?

Also:
Everytime the archetype gets added, it's ignored by default and I have to manually unignore it before it gets registered as a java project.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Must be an issue with you IDE. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Using IntelliJ .

Comment: `it uses its own pom.xml.` can you clarify what do you mean by it? What pom.xml is used for a new Maven module? What do you expect to have?

Comment: IDE should use the pom.xml of the `archetype` you select to create a module.